# Firebase + React Native + Sign in with Apple

Tags: firebase, react-native, apple-sign-in

I am trying to sign in with apple on Android using the `@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication` package found here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/ Currently I have iOS working, but having a difficult time getting back the UID from firebase on Android. I see no new added users in the console because I think I am sending the wrong info to Firebase?

I setup the necessary requirements for this to work with Android including making a serviceID on the apple dev site for web and enabled the OAuth in the firebase console. And place all the Ids and private keys in there respective fields.

```
  /**
   *
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   */
  const handleAppleLogin = async () => {
    // Generate secure, random values for state and nonce
    const rawNonce = uuid();
    const state = uuid();

    try {
      appleAuthAndroid.configure({
        clientId: 'LEFT_OUT_MATCHES_THE_APPLE_CLIENT_ID',
        redirectUri: 'LEFT_OUT_MATCHES_THE_APPLE_REDIRECT',
        scope: appleAuthAndroid.Scope.ALL,
        responseType: appleAuthAndroid.ResponseType.ALL,
        nonce: rawNonce,
        state,
      });

      const { id_token } = await appleAuthAndroid.signIn();

      const androidCredential = firebase.auth.OAuthProvider.credential(
        id_token,
        rawNonce,
      );

      const userCredential = await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithCustomToken(androidCredential.token);

      // ALSO TRIED .signInWithCredential(androidCredential);

      console.log('userCredential', userCredential);

      ...
```

Following along the docs: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/blob/master/example/app.android.js

I can get the id_token and everything that comes with `appleAuthAndroid.signIn();` and I can get the response of everything on `androidCredential` object including the `providerId` 'secret`, and` token`. It's the` userCredential` I am having issues with.

I am not getting back the UID from Firebase.

Comment: Could this be related to the comments on my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67261184/how-do-i-set-displayname-in-firebase-when-using-apple-authentication

Comment: @StevenMatthews Thanks for responding I stopped trying with Firebase Auth sign in going with native solutions. https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication