# How do I set displayName in Firebase when using Apple authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, apple-login

I am trying to use Apple OAuth on the web with the Firebase Javascript SDK, and when I do, the returned user object is fine, except for displayName, which is null.

```
  let provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("apple.com");
  provider.addScope("email");
  provider.addScope("name");
  let userCred = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
```

However when I look at the userCred I get:

```
displayName: null
```

I tried the scope `fullName` to no luck.

Is there any way to get the display name? I use it so that my users can see their name on the site, to personalize the experience.

Comment: Just to confirm: "Apple only shares user information such as the display name with apps the first time a user signs in. Usually, Firebase stores the display name the first time a user signs in with Apple, which you can get with firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName. However, if you previously used Apple to sign a user in to the app without using Firebase, Apple will not provide Firebase with the user's display name." Are you sure you are using it first time? and can you try using any other Apple ID ?

Comment: I don't really have another Apple ID available to me this moment. It's a new app, though I did use another login method briefly during development. Could that be the problem here? I have tested logging in with the Apple ID many times - is there any way to "reset' an Apple ID for firebase for testing?

Comment: Can you try deleting your account from the Firebase Console ?

Comment: I have deleted my account from Firebase console multiple times. No luck on that front. I'm getting someone else to try logging in.

Comment: I had someone else try it, and it does show up. So I guess it's just my Apple ID. I wonder if there's a way to reset that.

Comment: I guess that must be any of your privacy settings in Apple ID? I'm not sure as I don't have Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

You get this right on the response to appleAuth signin response

```
const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
      requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
      requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME]
    });
```

**appleAuthRequestResponse** will hold the name details.

Please note that, if you had already used your account for testing, you will have to login to your appleid and remove the apple sign in for your app, to test this.[ Also delete this user from firebase auth ]